# AutoLisp - Run PowerShell and Command Prompt Commands

Tags: lisp, autolisp

I'm looking to pull some system information into a cad program (DraftSight), using AutoLisp. I have most of what I'm trying to complete, but I'm having trouble in understanding how I'm suppose to pull the information back into the AutoLisp program.

I'm mainly trying to see the available RAM, the percentage of the CPU usage, and the number of enabled cores. I've found several PowerShell and Command Prompt commands to get these values, but the returned value is an object (see below), and it seems to be returning before the remote script is finished.

**Commands**

```lisp
;;; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ;;;

;; Machine's RAM Availability and Total

;; PowerShell (fast ~instant)
;; Availability (MiB) : (Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_OperatingSystem).FreePhysicalMemory/1024
;; Total (MiB)        : (Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_OperatingSystem).TotalVisibleMemorySize/1024

;; PowerShell (slow ~4s)
;; Setting varialbe   : $General_Info = systeminfo
;; Availability (MiB) : ($General_Info | Select-String 'Available Physical Memory:').ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim()
;; Total (MiB)        : ($General_Info | Select-String 'Total Physical Memory:'    ).ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim()

;; Legacy Software

;; Command Prompt (fast ~instant)
;; Availability (kiB) : wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory
;; Total(kiB)         : wmic OS get TotalVisibleMemorySize

;; Command Prompt (slow ~8s)
;; Availability (MiB) : systeminfo | find "Available Physical Memory"
;; Total(kiB)         : systeminfo | find "Total Physical Memory"

;;; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ;;;

;; Machine's CPU percentage and count

;; PowerShell (moderate ~0.5s)
;; Load Percentage     : gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor | Select -First 1 | %{'{0}%' -f $_.PercentProcessorTime}
;; NumberOfEnabledCore : 

;; PowerShell (slow ~2s)
;; Load Percentage     : (Get-WmiObject win32_processor).LoadPercentage
;; NumberOfEnabledCore : (Get-WmiObject win32_processor).NumberOfEnabledCore

;; Legacy Software

;; Command Prompt (semi-slow ~2s)
;; Load Percentage     : wmic cpu get loadpercentage
;; NumberOfEnabledCore : wmic cpu get NumberOfEnabledCore
```

**Code**

```lisp
(progn
    (setq WSript (vlax-get-or-create-object "WScript.Shell"))
    (setq PShell (vlax-invoke WSript 'exec "Powershell.exe (Get-WmiObject win32_processor).LoadPercentage"))
    (vlax-dump-object PShell)
    (vlax-release-object WSript)
    (vlax-release-object PShell)
    (gc)
)
; IWshExec: WSH Exec Object
; Property values:
;   ExitCode = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   ProcessID = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   Status = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   StdErr = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   StdIn = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   StdOut = Parameterized properties not displayed
```

```lisp
(progn
    (setq WSript (vlax-get-or-create-object "WScript.Shell"))
    (setq PShell (vlax-invoke WSript 'exec "cmd.exe wmic cpu get loadpercentage"))
    (vlax-dump-object PShell)
    (vlax-release-object WSript)
    (vlax-release-object PShell)
    (gc)
)
; IWshExec: WSH Exec Object
; Property values:
;   ExitCode = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   ProcessID = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   Status = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   StdErr = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   StdIn = Parameterized properties not displayed
;   StdOut = Parameterized properties not displayed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to invoke Powershell via Windows Script Host, as you can query WMI directly, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun LM:wmiquery ( cls prp / qry rtn srv wmi )
    (if (setq wmi (vlax-create-object "wbemscripting.swbemlocator"))
        (progn
            (setq rtn
                (vl-catch-all-apply
                   '(lambda ( / rtn )
                        (setq srv (vlax-invoke wmi 'connectserver)
                              qry (vlax-invoke srv 'execquery (strcat "select " prp " from " cls))
                        )
                        (vlax-for itm qry (setq rtn (cons (vlax-get itm prp) rtn)))
                    )
                )
            )
            (foreach obj (list qry srv wmi)
                (if (= 'vla-object (type obj)) (vlax-release-object obj))
            )
            (if (not (vl-catch-all-error-p rtn)) rtn)
        )
    )
)
```

```lisp
_$ (LM:wmiquery "WIN32_OperatingSystem" "FreePhysicalMemory")
("23059220")
_$ (LM:wmiquery "WIN32_OperatingSystem" "TotalVisibleMemorySize")
("33343316")
```

Comment: Thank you @Lee Mac. Is there a website where I can learn more about creating, navigating, and get/push information with these objects? I'm having trouble finding the right resources beyond `vlax-create-object` .

Answer (score 0):

For those using DraftSight or another cad application that doesn't like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75817754/8543948), this modification drills down a few extra object layers to find the desired information.

```lisp
(defun LM:wmiquery ( cls prp / qry rtn srv wmi fcnLambda obj)
    
    ;; Remote script object
    (setq wmi (vlax-create-object "wbemscripting.swbemlocator"))
    (if wmi (progn
        
        ;; Local function
        (setq fcnLambda
            (function (lambda ( / rtn itm1 itm2)
                (setq srv (vlax-invoke wmi 'connectserver))
                (setq qry (vlax-invoke srv 'execquery (strcat "select " prp " from " cls)))
                (vlax-for itm1 qry 
                    (if (vlax-property-available-p itm1 'properties_ )
                        (vlax-for itm2 (vlax-get itm1 'properties_ )
                            (if (= (strcase (vlax-get itm2 'Name))(strcase prp))
                                (setq rtn (cons (vlax-get itm2 'Value) rtn))
                            );if
                        );vlax-for
                    );if
                );vlax-for
                rtn
            ));function<-lambda
        );setq
        
        ;; Return value
        (setq rtn (vl-catch-all-apply 'fcnLambda))
        
        ;; Releasing objects
        (foreach obj (list qry srv wmi)
            (if (= 'vla-object (type obj)) (vlax-release-object obj))
        );foreach
        (gc)
        
        ;; Return value
        (if (not (vl-catch-all-error-p rtn)) rtn)
    ));if<-progn
);LM:wmiquery
```

```lisp
Command: (LM:wmiquery "win32_processor" "NumberOfEnabledCore")
(8)
Command: (LM:wmiquery "Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor" "PercentProcessorTime")
("4" "3" "9" "9" "9" "3" "3" "3" "0" "0" "0" "9" "3" "9" "3" "3" "3")
Command: (LM:wmiquery "WIN32_OperatingSystem" "FreePhysicalMemory")
("23256744")
Command: (LM:wmiquery "WIN32_OperatingSystem" "TotalVisibleMemorySize")
("33177712")
```